# Financial string to NSNumber NSNumberFormatter does not work for different region

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a financial string with I want to cover to NSNumber. Before I faced the issue I did it like that:

```
extension String { 
 var rawNumber: NSNumber? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter.number(from: self)
    }
}
```

When I get the number from "5.7" it worked great on the simulator. Perhaps because of United States region.

But real device with another region failed to convert string "5.7" until I relaized that the problem with locale I use

So I forced locale a bit and changed the code to this:

```
extension String {
    
    var rawNumber: NSNumber? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return numberFormatter.number(from: self.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))
    }
```

I need this number for feature calculation, for example for multiplying and etc. I use `NSDecimalNumber` for that purposes.

So now my code works. Not sure if it is good to force locale.

I tried to use numberFormatter.separator as dot and comma for different locale but it did not work for me.

So just forcing to `Locale(identifier: "en_US")` works and string can be converted to `NSNnumber`

I supposed if I will use different locales and different separators it will convert string to kind of `NSNumber.double(5.7)` whatever I used comma as separator or dot.

I've added needed if block to catch current local and depend on this I used different separators, but no luck.

So looks like `Locale(identifier: "en_US")` is only a solution here.

Comment: The correct approach will all depend on where the number is coming from and whether that can vary the formatting it uses. `en_US_POSIX` is a locale that is commonly used for handling API responses.

Comment: @CraigSiemens thanks for comment! yea I agree that it depends, one thing that I notice that formatter returns nil for Ukraine locale when I specify uk_UA and comma separator symbol `,`, weather I change locale or not. Seems it won't work with comma separators. Honestly for my purposes I just need double styled values to make calculation. So whatever which separator input I have. So for my appropriate case `en_US` or `en_US_POSIX` as you suggested will work.